# Finding directory path for .sty files

Tags: packages, paths

I am attempting to add the `subfloat.sty` file to my LaTeX search path. In order to find that path, I executed:

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
```

which, as expected, gave

> /home/max/texmf

However, there are no subdirectories associated with that (seemingly empty) path, and I cannot even cd to `~/texmf` nor copy files to this directory (consequently, I cannot move the `.sty` file into any subdirectory). However, I can run LaTeX successfully, including various other packages without error, so obviously it's looking for and finding them in some directory path, just not the one indicated.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to trouble-shoot this problem?

Comment: TEXINPUTS is the variable you want to inspect

Comment: If you have texlive or miktex you should just be able to update via the package manager.

Comment: Note that `subfloat.sty` should be located (if in `TEXMFHOME`) in `/home/max/texmf/tex/latex` unless you have already fiddled with `TEXINPUTS`,  `texmf.cnf`, etc. That is, `TEXMFHOME` should follow the pattern of `TEXMFMAIN`.  I'm guessing if you 'cannot even cd to `~/texmf`', then that means you have not created the folder yet..?

Comment: And are you sure you don't already have `subfloat.sty` installed? (Check with `kpsewhich subfloat.sty`.)

Comment: I don't have subfloat.sty.

Comment: To answer jon's question: my point is that I'm trying to find the directory path latex uses to find existing files. kpsewhich identifies /home/max/texmf, but there is nothing in that directory, meaning that latex is accessing some other directory (since it's able to find and load other packages like graphicsx.sty etc). It isn't a matter of creating a new directory, but finding which one latex is using as the default path.

Comment: There is `TEXMFMAIN` (global), `TEXMFLOCAL` (local), and `TEXMFHOME` (user-level), which are respectively listed in the reverse order in which they are searched (by default) by KPATHSEA (try `texdoc kpathsea` to learn more). Your distribution will install in `TEXMFMAIN` by default, and a 'full' installation of TeX Live will include the file at `$TEXMFMAIN/tex/latex/subfloat`. Packages you develop (e.g., `mypkg.sty`) should go in `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/mypkg`. Note: this assumes that you have installed TeX Live; if you are using your OS-based version, details may differ.

Comment: And, as I already suggested for `subfloat.sty`, to figure out where `graphicx.sty` is, you can do `kpsewhich graphicx.sty` (or more general tools, like `locate graphicx.sty` --- but this will only find the file, not give you any information about how TeX finds the file).

Answer (score 2):

The package `subfloat.sty` should be added to the LaTeX search path, i.e., if you have an openSUSE Linux machine, generally it is found to be in:

`/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/subfloat/`

and/or

`$HOME/texmf/tex/latex/subfloat/`.

If you have never added manually to your LaTeX distribution a package for the only user max, the directory `~/texmf` shouldn't exist. Furthermore, if you haven't added any other path to your `TEXMFHOME`, all the folders containing your LaTeX packages should be grouped in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex`.

The variables `TEXMFHOME` and your `TEXMFDIST` are defined in:

```
max@hostname ~: $ echo `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`
```

which should give as a result `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`.

Now, if the result of the following bash script is a message showing the word Yes or the word Nes (to execute a bash script: save it to a file named `compare.sh`, give it the proper permissions via `chmod +x compare.sh` and execute it via `./compare.sh`):

```
if grep -q "TEXMFDIST = /usr/share/texmf" `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`; then
    if grep -q "TEXMFHOME = {~/texmf" `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`; then
        echo "Yes"
    else
        echo "Nes"
    fi
else 
    echo "No"
fi
```

then you could try to follow this procedure:

1. Download the package subfloat from [CTAN: Direc­tory macros/latex/contrib/subfloat](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfloat) (wget is needed)
2. unpack the package `subfloat.zip`;
3. Run the script `subfloat.ins`;
4. Copy `subfloat.sty` to your LaTeX search path;
5. Optionally, copy the documentation in the documentation directory;
6. Update your LaTeX distribution.

```
max@hostname ~: $ wget mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfloat.zip # download link for subfloat, if you don't trust this, you can download it manually
max@hostname ~: $ unzip subfloat.zip
max@hostname ~: $ cd subfloat
max@hostname ~/subfloat: $ latex subfloat.ins
max@hostname ~/subfloat: $ sudo mkdir /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/subfloat
max@hostname ~/subfloat: $ sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/texmf/doc/subfloat
max@hostname ~/subfloat: $ sudo cp subfloat.sty /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/subfloat/
max@hostname ~/subfloat: $ sudo cp subfloat.pdf /usr/share/texmf/doc/subfloat
max@hostname ~/subfloat: $ sudo texhash # update your LaTeX distribution
```

Comment: This looks like the TeX distribution was installed from a package manager (e.g., `Apt`), not from upstream from TUG (i.e., 'vanilla' TeX), so these instructions are not generalized to a 'Linux machine'.   You also should not install the documentation in the same folder as the `.sty` file; use the result from `kpsewhich TEXDOCS` (likely, in this case, to be `$TEXMFMAIN/doc/latex/subfloat`).

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it is correct. However, this does not seem to be the case of a guy which installed TeX distribution from TUG, but I might be wrong. That's why now I will ask to @Max, what type od TeX distribution is installed on your machine?